# Android SharedPreferences api issues

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I googled for some API and examples of usage of SharedPreferences and I got this sort of a snippet:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
                          "com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

When I put it into my code, I got a compile error that getSharedPreferences is not a defined activity for DownloadWebPageTask

Any idea where I am making a bone headed mistake here and how I should actually be using SharedPreferences to get access to that file saved on the system?

Thanks!!

Comment: What is your `this` referring to? I assume you put the code under a class called `DownloadWebPageTask`, then `this` will be pointing to this class rather than the `YourActivity`. If so, you should use `YourActivity.this` instead to get the Activity instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you need different sets of preferences in the same application (unlikely) I suggest you use

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

(`this` needs to be a `Context` of course, e.g. an `Activity` or your `Application`)

Answer (score 2):

The getSharedPreferences method is a public method of Context class.
You need use a Context instance, you can pass it when create a DownloadWebPageTask instance.